# PHP TCPDF WriteHTML() Not Working POST or GET variable

Tags: variables, tcpdf

I create PDF with Tcpdf;
I have a problem with Writehtml();

When i use following code Not Problem.

```
$legend = '<img src="images/level7.gif">106 bis 109 <br><img src="images/level6.gif">102 bis 106 <br><img src="images/level5.gif">99 bis 102 <br><img src="images/level4.gif">95 bis 99 <br><img src="images/level3.gif">92 bis 95 <br><img src="images/level2.gif">88 bis 92 <br><img src="images/level1.gif">85 bis 88 <br><img src="images/level0.gif">Kein Wert vorhanden<br>";

$pdf->writeHTML($legend, true, 0, true, 0);
```

/* Working perfect*/

but when i try passing same data with POST or GET

```
$legend = $_GET['data'];
$pdf->writeHTML($legend, true, 0, true, 0);
```

pdf file is opening (no error) but no data...

I'm sure $_GET['data'] contains equal $legend...

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

```
$legend = htmlentities($_GET['legend']);
```

Comment: it is displaying html code in the PDF result with this function.